# Proj4js Problem in converting coordinates from google mercator

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, proj, web-mercator, mercator

I am a really beginner into web-cartography, so sorry if this subject is rudimentary or basic but I truly search for a long time and I am still stick in it.

So the problem is:

I don't understand why this code don't convert correctly my coordinates (exprimed in google mercator epsg:900913) to WGS84 web mercator epsg:4326:

```
   Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:900913"]= "+title=GoogleMercator +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs";

var dest = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:4326");    
var source = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:900913");
var point = new Proj4js.Point( 85286.417057415703, 4347668.9422677439 ); 
Proj4js.transform(source, dest, point);
var transformation = Proj4js.transform(source, dest, point);
alert(point.y + "," + point.x);
```

I should have in return x (long) = 0.7661409 and y(lat) =36.3411771 (calculated by http://twcc.free.fr/) but with this code I have:
x=0.0003264583485814848 y=0.000006882360979601046

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it, but you're converting twice. If I take the original values, unproject them, I get the twcc results. If I treat those results as EPSG:3857 and unproject them again, I get your results.

Answer (score 1):

Google Mercator is now EPSG:3857, while 900913 has been dropped from the list of EPSG codes.

Furthermore, there is some kind of hack inside the projection definition, because Google mercator is calculated on a sphere (a=b), but the lat/lon coordinates are that of the WGS84 ellisoid. This is only implemented correctly for EPSG:3857.

Comment: I try with these codes:                          Proj4js.defs["SR-ORG:6864"] =    "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";                                            Proj4js.defs["SR-ORG:7483"] = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs";                   wich are both epsg:3857, but I still have the same kind of results :(

Answer (score 1):

Different infos:

- some lines are not useful

By default, these below projections already exist so you do not need to declare them

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:900913"]= "+title=GoogleMercator +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs";
```

You also have to remove or the transformation happens twice as pointed by other answer.

```
Proj4js.transform(source, dest, point);
```

**So the minimum to get the result with you current code is:**

```
var src = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:900913");
var point = new Proj4js.Point(85286.417057415703, 4347668.9422677439); 
//Do your conversion 
Proj4js.transform(src, Proj4js.WGS84, point) 
//The point object no has the converted coordinates 
console.log(point.x + "," + point.y);
```

For the last line, don't use `alert`: it's an outdated practice when there was no browser debugger. You should see a bit browser debugging at http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

- You can maybe use the updated version of the library (the 2.x series) from http://proj4js.org (where you will also find the example I will use below)

With the proj4js v2.x, your projection conversion is possible with just below lines:

```
var coordinatesEPSG4326 = proj4('EPSG:3857').inverse([85286.417057415703, 4347668.9422677439]);
console.log(coordinatesEPSG4326);
```

Comment: Jus added answer here although forgot I already gave you an anwer some months ago on the French forum http://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=94068 ;)